# Archiving old mail from IMAP to local disk in batch mode

Tags: imap, archiving, fetchmail, maildir

I have an IMAP account with limited space. I would like to archive "old" mails to local storage, and I want to do it automatically (from cron) on my Linux system. I still want to keep the latest mail (up to a year or so) on the IMAP server.

What is the best way to do this automatic archiving? Is it fetchmail I am looking for?

What is a good format for the local storage? I assume Maildir is a good choice.

Answer (score 1):

it is fetchmail, http://www.andrews-corner.org/mutt.html - just replace: 'POP3' => 'IMAP', 'no keep' => 'keep', write a some wrapper (`su user -c fetchmail`) and put it under cron.

btw, mailbox is better, for example you can use munpack utility with it.

Comment: Please explain how to make fetch download and remove old mails and leave the newer ones.